# Read many files from Kafka Connect FileStreamSourceTask

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am reading 1 log file in Kafka, and creating a topic. This is succesful. To read this file, I am editing the file *config/connect-file-source.properties* to this purpose, and according to Step 7 of Kafka Quickstart (http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnect).

But, now, I would like to read a lot of files. In the file *config/connect-file-source.properties* I have edited the variable *file* with a pattern, for instance:
*file=/etc/logs/archive*.log*
Because I want to read all the files of the directory logs, with the pattern **archive*.log**. But, this line doesn't work.

What is the best form to implement the reading of files with a pattern, using the file *config/connect-file-source.properties* ?

Answer (score 4):

In `config/connect-file-source.properties`,

source class is `FileStreamSource` and it uses task class as [`FileStreamSourceTask`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/41e676d29587042994a72baa5000a8861a075c8c/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceTask.java#L79).

It reads a file using `FileInputStream`, so it cannot open multiple files at once. (by passing a directory name or regex pattern..)

You should implement your own `Source` & `SourceTask` class, or use an existing one that supports this feature such as [kafka-connect-spooldir](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)

Comment: Thanks @Geunho for your answer.

Comment: But, what if I don't have the opportunity to develop? I mean, I only have acces to log path to read the files and pass it to Kafka (or another option?)

Comment: Another alternative connector for streaming many files into kafka : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse